# Cant read files - java.io.FileNotFoundException: (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I've created a simple Java application that tries to read in a file, and complete an action on the file.

**Problem**:
Upon requesting the file with the absolute path I get an FileNotFoundException.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    String path = "/Users/kentandersen/Downloads/greendaoprotobuf-master/test";
    File files = new File(path);

    System.out.println(files.getAbsoluteFile());
    System.out.print(files.canRead() + "\n");

    //Error occurs here.
    String[] fileNames = new Scanner(files, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next().split("\n");
}
```

Below are the logs.

```
/Users/kentandersen/Downloads/greendaoprotobuf-master/test
true
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/kentandersen/Downloads/greendaoprotobuf-master/test (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:654)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The logs clearly state that I can read those files, and then Scanner runs and says it doesn't exist.

I can copy the absolute path in the logs and CD to that location, and it takes me there.

I'm using Intellij 13.

Comment: Thats shown in the logs. It says "true".

Comment: What do you get when you call `files.toString()` and print that to the console?

Comment: @fe11e toString() = /Users/kentandersen/Downloads/greendaoprotobuf-master/test

Comment: is 'test' a directory?  or a file?  @perencia is correct, I just checked, you can't point a Scanner at a directory you will get a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: it is a directory. I was under the impression that it would still read it though.

Comment: Nope, @perencia is correct, you want files.listFiles()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Scanner` on a directory. You should use it on a file.

```
/Users/kentandersen/Downloads/greendaoprotobuf-master/test
```

is a directory.

Try something like

```
files.listFiles()
```

Comment: You can use Scanner on a directory. There is not such restriction

Comment: I guess so there is one constructor which let you pass the path.

Comment: @Ashish but paths to files, i'd say.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.nio.file.Path)

Comment: Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file